# enforcing a class to be used only as a shared pointer

Tags: c++11

In order to prevent bad usage of a class T and shared_ptr (typically, constructing multiple shared_ptrs from the same T*, resulting in double free) I thought to **force** shared pointers to be used, by making the class constructor private, and adding a factory method to create a shared_ptr.

Question 1: is this a bad approach and why?

I abstracted all the above functionality into this base class template:

```
#include <memory>

template<typename T>
class add_make_shared : public std::enable_shared_from_this<T>
{
public:
    typedef std::shared_ptr<T> Ptr;

    template<typename... Args>
    static Ptr make_shared(Args&&... args)
    {
        return Ptr(new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
    }
};
```

I also inherit from enable_shared_from_this because it is useful in this scenario (although is not required at all).

Then, for every class A for which we want to enforce this policy, we have to do:

```
class A : public add_make_shared<A>
{
private:
    friend class add_make_shared<A>;

    A(...) { ... }

public:
    ...
};
```

basically:

- declare add_make_shared as friend, because it needs to construct A
- declare A's constructor private

(Provided that you answered no to Question 1) Question 2: is this implementation optimal or how can be improved?

For my taste is still a bit verbose, due to the two above points.

Comment: That's not going to stop people from getting a raw pointer from your shared_ptr, or subsequently constructing another shared_ptr from that raw pointer.

Comment: true, but it is going to limit it in many ways